# Probability of G(3, 1/2) random graph being connected

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a random undirected graph G(3,1/2), i.e. the probability of any two of the three total  vertices being connected is 1/2.

The probability of this graph being connected is supposedly 1/2. Why?

Comment: Research effort shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a list of all graphs on three vertices, and assign a probability to each of them (for example, three disconnected vertices have probability $1/8$th, as does a $K_3.$) Now just count.